# Using Interbase Api in Delphi

Tags: delphi

This is my Delphi code to add user to Interbase security database

```
uses 
  IBHeader,IBExternals

var
  Form7: TForm7;
  userData: TUserSecData;
  userDataPtr: PUserSecData;
  status: array[0..19] of ISC_STATUS;
  isc_status: PISC_STATUS;

procedure TForm7.Create_UserClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { setup isc_status pointer }
  isc_status :=@status;
  { setup user data pointer to point to user data structure }
  userDataPtr :=@userData;
  { setup user data structure }
  userData.user_name :='aseem';

  userData.password :='xxxxxxx';

  userData.protocol :=sec_protocol_local;

  userData.dba_user_name :='SYSDBA';

  userData.dba_password :='xxxxxxx'; { Don_t hardcode this }

  userData.first_name :='asa';

  userData.last_name :='sad';

  userData.sec_flags :=sec_password_spec or sec_dba_user_name_spec or
    sec_dba_password_spec or sec_first_name_spec or sec_last_name_spec;

  { add user to security database }
  isc_add_user(isc_status,userDataPtr);

end;
```

But there is one error like

> isc_add_user(isc_status,userDataPtr);
>
> function is not found in IBheader.pas,IBExternals

Can you please tell me what is the problem in this code?

I am using Delphi 2007 professional edition and I'm using the IBheader.pas, IBExternals.pas files that are in the source folder inside CodeGear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the interface defined in the IBIntf.pas:

```
uses IBHeader, IBExternals, IBIntf;

procedure TMyForm.RegisterNewUser;
var
  status: ISC_STATUS;
  status_vector: array[0..19] of ISC_STATUS;
  user_sec_data: UserSecData;
  gds: IGDSLibrary; 
begin
  //setup the user info and then
  ...
  //call the function
  gds := GetGDSLibrary;
  gds.LoadLibrary;
  try
    status := gds.isc_add_user(@status_vector[0], @user_sec_data);
    //check the status and act accordingly
  finally
    gds.FreeLibrary;
  end;
end;
```

Or you may want to use the TIBSecurityService, which is part of IBX, the same library that provides the headers you're using, by calling it's AddUser method.

Or, in modern Interbase, you may want to just execute a `CREATE USER` SQL statement to perform that action.

Comment: Thank you Mr. jachguate this is working with function gds.LoadIBLibrary;

Comment: @Aseem you welcome. Take in account now I fixed a bug in the code (I'm not passing a vector where it's supposed to).

Answer (score 1):

Download **Unified Interbase** library and copy all needed API declarations from it

TLama also suggests this article: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25831

Comment: @TLama that is a stand-alone answer in its full rights, not a mere comment

Comment: feel free to include it to your answer. I'm going to delete mine in few minutes. And it's not so much standalone since it's just a link ;-)